# Pycharm will not recognize opencv3

Tags: python, opencv, package

so guys after a painful day I have finally gotten opencv to be recognized in python 3 :

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.1.0'
```

but when I do this in Pycharm the result is:

```
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 "/Users/saminahbab/Documents/directory/Image Recognition /pictures/searcher.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saminahbab/Documents/directory/Image Recognition /pictures/searcher.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

which could be for a number of reasons, i have tried to do all sorts of symlinks within reason, trying pyenv among others 
now I know that these are different python builds but I wouldnt know to unify them so as to get cv2 working on pycharm and also keep all of my other packages that I will be using in conjunction. anyone with any advice?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get PyCharm working with OpenCV 3 is as follows:

1. Install Anaconda to a directory that doesn't require admin access from https://www.continuum.io/downloads
2. Create a virtual environment (optional):

   `conda create -n <yourEnvName> python=<yourPython3Version> anaconda`

   `source activate <yourEnvName>` (source is not required if you are using the anaconda prompt in Windows)
3. Install OpenCV 3: `conda install -n <yourEnvName> -c https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3`
4. Setup PyCharm: Open PyCharm --> File --> Settings --> Project --> Project Interpreter --> Click on the config wheel, select "Add Local".
   Add `<yourAnacondaDir>\envs\<yourEnvName>\python.exe` and wait till PyCharm is done indexing

Finally, create a new python file and check if opencv 3 has been setup properly by typing:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```